# Excel VBA word boundaries (replacing prepositions)

Tags: regex, vba, excel

What I need to do is to add a plus `+` sign before every preposition in the cell? For some reason, `\b` won't work for me.

In JavaScript, it should work just fine:

```
(\bof\b|\bat\b)
//change with
+$1
```

But VBA script in Excel with the same regex won't match anything.

Example:

```
И отдохнуть от них было для него спасением от мук.
```

The result should be:

```
И отдохнуть +от них было +для него спасением +от мук.
```

Note that "отдохнуть" word has "от" inside.

Code itself (taken somewhere here):

```
Sub ReplaceWithRe()
Dim re As Object 'RegExp
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sReplace As String
Dim aReplace(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As String
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") ' New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.MultiLine = True

' Load array of patterns and replacements
aReplace(0, 0) = "(\bот\b|\bдля\b)"
aReplace(0, 1) = "+$1"

For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        For Each cl In rng
            sReplace = cl.Value
            ' Test each cell for each pattern, replace when found
            For i = 0 To UBound(aReplace, 1)
                re.Pattern = aReplace(i, 0)
                If re.Test(sReplace) Then
                    sReplace = re.Replace(sReplace, aReplace(i, 1))
                End If
            Next
            cl.Value = sReplace
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I think I got a hint. It looks like this regex works fine with Latin characters, but with Cyrillic it returns no matches. I've updated example.

Comment: Your code for us to check?

Comment: @JLILIAmen code added

Comment: There aren't any matches for your pattern there. It should be: `aReplace(0, 0) = "(\bon\b|\bwith\b)"` for your sample text.

Comment: @Rory That was not real life example. The problem is in cyrllic characters, with Latin regex works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for Cyrillic characters, you should be aware that as per [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html), VBScript regex has

> No Unicode support, except for matching single characters with

So, `\b` matches at a non-word boundary and the Cyrillic letters are non-words for VBScript regex engine!

The only way out is to expand the `\b` like this, e.g.:

```
strPattern = "(\s|^)(от|для)(\s|$)" 
str = "Отдохнуть от них было для него спасением от мук и прекрасным отдыхом."
strReplace = "$1+$2$3"
```

I think we can safely use spaces as delimiters since prepositions are not usually followed by punctuation. You can add punctuation to the first part though (just in case):

```
strPattern = "([\s,:;]|^)(от|для)(\s|$)"
```

Output:

```
Отдохнуть +от них было +для него спасением +от мук и прекрасным отдыхом.
```

Comment: I agree, `"\b(of|at)\b"` does not work. `"\b(on|with|of|at)\b"` works.

Comment: I got you, the example here was just an example. Thank you for your "not in the right place" irony. Example updated, the thing is I actually need it for cyrillic characters and it looks like \b works fine for me when I use latin character / latin string. But when I use Russian characters it stops working.

Comment: A very nice riddle, thank you for a good question. Cyrillic letters were key to understanding the issue.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm. Learn and live, better to put real example instead of anything else.