# preg_match find exact matching with multilanguage is not working

Tags: php, regex

When I tried with Burmese language its not returning correct data. I don't know where I am going wrong here. Please help me to find issue or give me per fact solution

Thanks in advance

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

/*$text = " 蝯 榩榿榩榿榩榿 @逯郹酟 勯噚嶢, 潫 橀槶澉 莦莚虙 弣抶 蒆葞 "; //Some text
$keyword = "箖緌翢";*/

$text  ="အေမရိကန္အေျခစိုက္ Chevrolet ကားကုမၸဏီ၏ ၂၀၁၅ ကိုလာ ေမာ္ဒယ္ Chevrolet Malibu";
$keyword = "ကိုလာ";


function find_keywords($text,$search_keywords){
    /*
        $text : String value
        $search_keywords : String value 
        Function : Seperating search_keywords variable through commna identifier and exact matching.
        Return type : boolean
    */
    if(empty($search_keywords) || empty($text))
        return false;

    $search_keywords_arr=explode(",", $search_keywords);    
    foreach($search_keywords_arr as $keyword) {
        //if(preg_match("/\b".trim($keyword)."\b/i", $text) == true) return true;   
        if(preg_match_all("/(*UTF8)\b($keyword)\b/ui", $text) == true) return true;     
    }
    return false;
}

if(find_keywords($text,$keyword)) echo "Match"; else echo "Not matched";
```

Comment: Please paste the text somewhere where we can see it. I think you can safely remove `(*UTF8)` from your pattern.

Comment: It seems that the word boundary on the right makes your pattern fail, the next character after the keyword seems to be `" ေ"` *(so it isn't a space)*, and the whole word seems to be `"ကိုလာ ေ"` *(if I trust the word boundary)*, I can't say more since I don't know this language, are you sure that the keyword is a whole word? Indeed `(*UTF8)` is not needed, since the u modifier already switches this mode on. However, you can always remove the u modifier and add `(*UTF8)(*UCP)` at the begining, it is the same.

Comment: [A similar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255964/excel-vba-word-boundaries-replacing-prepositions/30258076#30258076) was in VBA regex with `\b`, I think. I had to use `(\s|^)$keyword(\s|$)`. Also, what about `declare(encoding="utf-8");`?

Answer (score 0):

Because some multibyte characters fall outside of the range covered by the word boundary character (`\b`), you will need to manually express the characters that should identify the boundaries.

My snippet will lookaround for start/end of string, whitespace characters, and unicode punctuation characters.  This should get you started, then you can modify if/as needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jJvkD))

```
function find_keywords($text, $search_keywords) {
    if (empty($search_keywords) || empty($text)) {
        return false;
    }

    $search_keywords_arr = explode(",", $search_keywords);    
    foreach ($search_keywords_arr as $keyword) {   
        if (preg_match('/(?<=^|\s|\p{P})' .preg_quote($keyword, '/') . '(?=\p{P}|\s|$)/ui', $text)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$text = "အေမရိကန္အေျခစိုက္ Chevrolet ကားကုမၸဏီ၏ ၂၀၁၅ ကိုလာ, ေမာ္ဒယ္ Chevrolet Malibu";
$keyword = "ကိုလာ";
echo find_keywords($text, $keyword) ? "Match" : "Not matched";
```

Output:

```
Match
```